# Why would an arp table be incomplete?

Tags: macos, nmap, arp

Last night I connected to a local BT Fon network that my housemate was already on. My aim was to find his mac address, so I did an arp -a command (from OS X) and it returned only the router address.

Can someone tell me why this is?

Would nmap -sP be the next line of 'attack' when something like this fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the widespread substitution of hubs with switches (can you guys still find hubs anywhere????), icmp traffic does not indiscriminately reach all users attached to the same switch. So, while you will certainly see both broadcast and unicast (to you!) icmp traffic, you should not be able to see anything else. This is done for security reasons. Having both IP address and MAC address of a host, you can play a number of tricks on them, like MIM attacks (Man In the Middle); or you can evade the security in captive-portal networks, and get to the Internet for free.

To ascertain whether icmp traffic is controlled on your network, try:

```
  ping -c1 -b 192.168.1.255
```

where the IP address above should be the broadcast address of your network, and see whether you get any reply at all. If you do not, chances are icmp traffic is being closely controlled.

As a matter of fact, in these cases it is much simpler to sniff an IP/MAC duo via wifi: just put your wifi card into monitor mode, and listen to all icmp traffic: you should be able to see then both queries (*who has 192.168.1.113? Tell 192.168.1.1*) and replies (*192.168.1.113 is at 00:11:22:33:44:55*). This does require of course that you and the mark are physically close, of course.